# PostgreSQL client v10 or v11, with v9 server

Tags: postgresql

We have a PostgreSQL server, which we just upgraded from 9.3 to 9.5. All our machines have the 9.3 client package installed, and as a result, `pg_dump` no longer works, since it's not forward-compatible.

We have to upgrade the client software, obviously - my question is, which version should we upgrade to? I was initially thinking we should go to 9.6, which is the latest release in the 9.* series, to save us from doing this in the future if we upgrade the server again. But if so, then why not go to 10 or 11? Are there any downsides to mixing major versions like this? Are the 10 and 11 clients considered stable?

Answer (score 1):

My advice would be to upgrade the client to stay compatible on the same version as your server (like pg_dump v9.5.x work with 9.5.x postgres servers). You could use version 10 to do pg_dump on version 9.5.x, but then you'd have to be prepared to deal with any bugs that could crop up from expecting to do that daily.

On the surface, even though the changes that occurred to the pg_dump command were new command arguments (shown below), I doubt the testing is  as rigorous for the different permutations of backups using clients on future versions to older versions of postgresql server.

- 9.6 introduced the `--strict-names argument`
- 10 introduced the `--no-blobs` `--no-publications` `--no-subscriptions` `--no-sync`
  arguments

Since doing the backup doesn't always have to be invoked locally on the server itself, you can always have different machines for this purpose (to invoke backup remotely)

Depending on the operating system and package manager, the newer version of pg_dump is probably sitting on the server already like in 
 **/usr/lib/postgresql/your_server_version_here/bin/**, you could always create a symlink to the new version like so (assumed debian system):

```
sudo ln -s --force /usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/bin/pg_dump /usr/bin/pg_dump
```